# Command script with multiple lines

Tags: command-line, libreoffice

I want to convert multiple .odt files to PDF with a single click. Therefore, I have to specify the directory and run the command. I don't know how to combine these two actions in one .bat file
`cd C:\Users\...\New folder` with
`For %f in (*.odt) do ("C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\swriter.exe" --headless --convert-to pdf %f)`
I was trying the backslash, &&, and echo to no avail.
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If the for-loop works when run in the correct directory, this should do the trick in a .bat file:

```
For %%f in (C:\<full path>\*.odt) do ("C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\swriter.exe" --headless --convert-to pdf %%f)
```

Comment: Nobody has pointed out that in a script, as against at the prompt, you double up the percent signs in FOR constructs so that `for %f` and `... --headless --convert-to pdf %f` become  `for %%f` and `... --headless --convert-to pdf %%f`

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks a lot for notifying me of my oopsie :-)